# Why did Harry name one of his kids after Luna?

Tags: harry-potter, names

Harry named his kids after six people:

- James (Potter)
- Sirius (Black)
- Lily (Evans)
- Luna (Lovegood)
- Albus (P.W.B. Dumbledore)
- Severus (Snape)

With the exception of Luna, all the other figures were people who had died.
<sub>(Luna is known to have survived from [the family tree](http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Harry---Friends-Family-Trees-harry-potter-581328_500_343.jpg) in *J.K. Rowling: A Year in the Life* and from the [2014 QWC articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gixH.jpg).)</sub>

J.K. Rowling has [previously described](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/670285105953415168) Harry's choice as "perpetuat[ing] the names of [those] who had nobody in their families to do so."

### So why did he name a kid after Luna if she didn't die?

<sub><sub>Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149024/why-wasnt-a-child-named-after-neville)</sub></sub>

Comment: @SQB - Hmm, not sure. It is a very similar question, but none of the many answers posted there would satisfactorily answer this one.

Comment: Hm, I see it's already been closed as a duplicate. May I advise to include a reference to the other question, explaining why you don't feel it answers your question? Although you probably know the drill.